# What's wrong with defining composition this way?

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

I was going through [some Arrow tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/StephensArrowTutorial), toying with functions returning a new version of themselves in an attempt to maintain some state.

The new type is defined like that:

```
newtype Circuit a b = Circuit {runCircuit :: a -> (b, Circuit a b)}
```

Because I want to be able to compose circuits I make it an instance of Category.  When composing two circuits, the result must also be a circuit.  `(Circuit b c) . (Circuit a b)` gives a `Circuit a c`.

I wrote this :

```
import qualified Control.Category as Cat
instance Cat.Category Circuit where
    (Circuit g) . (Circuit f) = Circuit $ \a -> let
                                                    (b, new_f) = f a
                                                    (c, new_g) = g b
                                                    new_circ = new_g . new_f
                                                in (c, new_circ)
```

but it fails:

```
Main.hs:70:64:
    Couldn't match expected type `b0 -> c0'
                with actual type `Circuit b c'
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `new_g'
    In the expression: new_g . new_f
    In an equation for `new_circ': new_circ = new_g . new_f
```

I looked up the answer in the tutorial and this answer was introducing an intermediate function like this, which compiles nicely:

```
(.) = dot where
    (Circuit g) `dot` (Circuit f) = Circuit $ \a -> let
                                                        (b, new_f) = f a
                                                        (c, new_g) = g b
                                                        new_circ = new_g `dot` new_f
                                                    in (c, new_circ)
```

I fail to see the difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.` in `new_g . new_f` is from the prelude, not from `Control.Category`. So you need to use `Cat..`.

But the usual way to use `Control.Category` is:

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))
import Control.Category
```

Comment: Perfect, adding `Cat.` just works.  Thanks for the advice, I see now why we would want to hide id and (.).